# Using custom controls in full-screen mode of windows media player control in C#

Tags: c#, axwindowsmediaplayer

I have written a video player app that uses the WindowsMediaPlayer control. I have since started to use photoshop a bit and so decided to create my own buttons and controls for it so I could make it respond in exactly the way I want it to. I created a new user control which has a panel with the new buttons docked to the bottom of the control and a WindowsMediaPlayer control with the "uimode" property set to "none" filling the rest of the control. This all works fine.

The problem is that if you are viewing a video in full-screen mode you don't get any buttons when the mouse is moved. Does anyone know if it's possible to have a panel appear on top of the full screen in, say, the bottom left corner of the screen without exiting full screen mode? I'm assuming the code would go in the MouseHover event and would start with an if statement so it only fires if the fullscreen property is true.

It's also not 100% necessary that I even use the WindowsMediaPlayer control. I only picked this because I was familiar with it. If anyone knows any other controls that would achieve what I'm after then I'd be open to looking into them.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a MouseMove event, so.

```
private void MediaPlayer_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
   // Do a check to see if the player is fullscreen
   // Show button panel - you could use a group box for this if you wanted
   GroupBox.Left = 0;
   GroupBox.Top = 0; 
   GroupBox.Visible = True;
}
```